# links nav issue in local hosts

Tags: html, localhost

so i'm working on a localhost server and i can seem to find a way to links pages without adding https:// or localhost/

for example

```
<a href='pagev1'>click here to go to page 1</a> [ im in ,, localhost/file1 url ]
```

if someone clicks on that link it will transfer them to that page as so ==> `[ localhost/file1/page1]`

the issue is , when someone at let say `[ localhost/file1/home/]` and if  he was on that url and clicked on iit ==> `[localhost/file1/home/pagev1]`   and it will show 404 page how can i fix that

i don't know what it called or what to type to find some answers about this topic because im still learning and my english as you can see not that great ,

and i can't just copy and paste the same localhost url because i want to deploy it on a vps so i dont have to change the links form localhost to the site domain

Comment: You can use relative link like `<a href="/file/home/yourpage.html">text of link</a>`.  It works on the same domain (in this case `localhost`), and the path is relative to the root of your domain. [A link for learn the `a` TAG.](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what you're trying to say. It sounds like you want to navigate between *home* and *page1* within *file1*

I looks like you're simply missing a forward slash from the "href" attribute on the  tag.

```
<a href='/file1/page1'>click here to go to page 1</a>
```

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45128720/links-of-href-http-localhost-in-html-code-at-server-cannot-be-reached-fr) out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding ./ as seen below. I think that's what you mean but I was a little confused from reading your problem description.

The "." may or may not be necessary depending on how your files are structured.

```
<a href='./pagev1'>click here to go to page 1</a> [ im in ,, localhost/file1 url ]
```